# eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am asked to diagonalize the following matrix:

$$ A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1-i\\
1+i & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

For that, I first found the eigenvalues already, which are $2$ and $-1$.

For $\lambda=2$, I found that its associate eigenvector is $(0,0)$, by solving the system

$$-x+(1-i)y=0$$
$$(1+i)x-y=0$$

but I know that this cannot happen.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: $(0,0)$ is never an eigenvector.

Comment: In the equation -x+ (1- I)y= 0, the coefficient of x is -1 where it should be 0, the upper left entry in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $(0,0)$ is never called an eigenvector because it solves *any* homogeneous linear system.

You need to incorporate $\lambda$ in the equations:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
-\lambda x+(1-i)y&=&0\\
(1+i)x+(1-\lambda)y&=&0
\end{eqnarray}$$

In your system for $\lambda=2$ there is a factor 2 missing in the first equation; it should read

$$\begin{eqnarray}
-2 x+(1-i)y&=&0\\
(1+i)x-y&=&0
\end{eqnarray}$$

This gives the nonzero eigenvector with coordinates $(1,1+i).$

Comment: What about the other eigenvector?
Would it be the solution of:

$$x+(1-i)y=0$$
$$(1+i)x+2y=0$$

?

Comment: This thing doesn't look like it has any solutions besides the trivial one.

Comment: But it does have nontrivial solutions; that is precisely what the characteristic equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ guarantees. An $n\times n$ homogeneous linear system has nontrivial solutions if and only if the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Given that 2 is an eigenvalue of $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1- i \\ 1+ i & 1\end{pmatrix}$ then there must exist a **non-zero** vector $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1- i \\ 1+ i & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 2a \\ 2b \end{pmatrix}$.

Doing the matrix multiplication on the left, that gives $\begin{pmatrix} (1- i)b \\ (1+ i)a+ b\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}2a \\ 2b \end{pmatrix}$.  That gives the two equations $(1+ i)b= 2a$ and $(1- i)a+ b= 2b$ or $(1- i)a= b$.  From the first equation $a= \frac{1+ i}{2}b$.  Putting that into second equation, $(1- i)\frac{1+ i}{2}b= b = b$.  That is true for **all** b! So an eigenvector, corresponding to eigenvalue 2, is $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+i}{2}b \\ b\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+ i}{2} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}b$ where b is any non-zero number.

Perhaps what you are missing is that, given an eigenvalue, there does not exist one unique eigenvector.  For any eigenvalue, the set of corresponding eigenvectors forms a **subspace** of the original vector space so there are necessarily an infinite number or eigenvectors.  Here, any non-zero multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+i}{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ (or $\begin{pmatrix} 1+ i \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$) is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 2.